# Величина (доля чего-то) увеличилась с 2% до 5%. Она увеличилась на 3% или на 150%?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, стилистика, общие-вопросы, числительные

Представим, что у нас есть статистические данные:
**В 2017-м году процент брака на предприятии был 2%, а в 2018-м – 5%**
**Можно ли сказать, что процент брака увеличился на 3% ?**
Что об этом говорят нормы русского языка? 
По факту, количество бракованных деталей увеличилось в 2,5 раза (т.е. на 150%). Следовательно, и их доля возросла на 150%. 
Будет ли ошибкой сказать про 3%?

Comment: Русский язык тут совершенно ни при чём. Тут голая математика.

Comment: Ну спасибо хоть не экономика предприятия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Что об этом говорят нормы русского языка?**

В русском языке есть понятие "процентный пункт". В Вашем случае можно сказать так: **процент брака увеличился на 3 процентных пункта.** Вместо "процент" можно сказать "доля", чтобы избежать повторения слов.

**Будет ли ошибкой сказать про 3%?**

Да, это грубая ошибка.

Comment: Не понял про долю. Если написать "За год **доля** брака увеличилась на 3%" ошибки не будет?

Comment: Будет. Доля брака увеличилась на 3 процентных пункта, а не на 3%.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 1):

В соответствии с нормами русского языка и математики, если величина Х увеличилась на 3 процента, то стало (Х + Х*0,03). Если процент брака был равен 2, а затем увеличился **на 3 процента**, то процент брака стал равен 2,06 (2 + 2*0,03 = 2,06). А вот сказать, что процент брака увеличился **на 3**, — верно (2 + 3 = 5).

А чтобы избежать недоразумений, лучше сказать, что процент брака вырос с двух до пяти.